# how to send values to a sevlet from a html updated by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets

```
<form method="post" action="../SubCategory">
 <div id="destinationFields">
   //after the page loaded i will drag and drop some divs fromsourceFields by jquery plugin
 </div>
<button type="submit" id="button">Add</button>
</form>

 <div id="sourceFields">

   <div>
   <label class="control-label"  id="label" for="Name">size:</label>
   <input type="hidden" value="1" name="labelValue" />
  </div>

   <div>
   <label class="control-label"  id="label" for="Name">Brand :</label>
   <input type="hidden" value="2" name="labelValue" />
  </div>

   <div>
   <label class="control-label"  id="label" for="Name">width:</label>
   <input type="hidden" value="3" name="labelValue" />
  </div>

 </div>
```

this is how the page is loading, there are some elements(divs) out of the **form** (you can see that in **sourceFields**)

i will drag and drop it into **destinationFields** but after i press submit and check  in the sevlet the changes are not done 
(i think it means the actual html is not changing)

Answer (score 0):

Using Ajax call .
For more detail visit given url:-
http://www.programming-free.com/2012/08/ajax-with-jsp-and-servlet-using-jquery.html